# Are there any other marine animals in Sharknado?

Tags: sharknado

From watching the movie, it appears that the only things that Sharknado picked up was sharks. But the ocean is filled with other life forms - fish small and large, mammals (cetaceans), etc...

Did the Sharknado pick up any of those lifeforms?

If not, is it explained in the movie WHY <strike>it ran a `"SELECT * FROM ocean WHERE animalType = 'Shark'"`</strike> only sharks were lifted by the tornado?

Comment: Because then it would have to be called "Fishnado" which doesn't sound as good.

Comment: @DJClayworth If I went to a sushi bar offering a "Fishnado" maki, I'd order it!

Comment: http://metro.co.uk/2013/08/07/sharknado-star-tara-reid-confuses-everyone-with-her-explanation-of-whale-sharks-on-discovery-channel-3915721/

Comment: Because the people who came up with the idea of a sharknado where most likely high at the time and didnt think about other marine life

Comment: Is this sci-fi?!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Sci-Fi, I think.

Comment: It is an honour and a privilege to vtc such a fine (if off-topic) question of yours, DVK!

Comment: So the argument here is that sharks really get sucked up into storms, and really fly through the air in tornadoes decapitating people, and therefore it isn't really science fiction or fantasy?  Just because a movie is horrible doesn't mean it is off topic.

Comment: Whether or not Sharknado is on-topic for this site is [being discussed on meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4880/is-sharknado-scifi).

Comment: @Wikis - looks like the consensus trends to "On-topic" so far

Comment: Yeah, and that's fine. I saw in your first revision you apologised, no need of course! It's not about me being right, it's about us getting to the best decision and then we all win.

Comment: **Turtlenado** has some possiblities...

Comment: @Oldcat - for $Deity's sake, don't give them ideas!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think @DJClayworth answer that he added in comments is correct. I see no reason that there are no other animals or fish inside of it. But alternately, there were other things inside of the tornado, beside Sharks that got sucked into the air or they got blown along, the sharks are just the main idea.

[Here:](http://io9.com/we-asked-the-writer-of-sharknado-some-very-serious-ques-736131336) This is regarding the Older movie so it might not help.

> Why a tornado and not a hurricane? Wouldn't that make more sense?
>
> Actually, we have both. In the movie an unprecedented hurricane sweeps
>   up the Pacific coast from Mexico towards L.A. driving all the sharks
>   in this part of the ocean before it. The hurricane floods the streets
>   of L.A., which is woefully unprepared for a hurricane. (Up to this
>   point, it’s all fairly accurate and something we should be thinking
>   about, disaster preparedness-wise). **Naturally these floodwaters are
>   filled with sharks!** **And then, as often happens, the hurricane spins
>   off tornadoes over the ocean. As anyone would expect, the tornadoes
>   suck up thousands of sharks. This all just seems like common sense to
>   me…**

So all I can think of is that, based on these quotes, the movie was not about anything else other than sharks and it was not suppose to be factual and intelligent(just entertaining).

> How did you come up with such a blisteringly awesome concept?
>
> Well, the Asylum (the company that produced the movie for Syfy) came
>   to me just after I’d completed writing/directing duties on last year’s
>   American Battleship (sorry, “American Warships”) and asked me to pitch
>   them ideas for a movie called “Shark Storm”. I asked if this would be
>   a straight up movie about sharks attacking during a storm or a crazy
>   storm made up of sharks. They said it would be straight, so I
>   declined, feeling like we’d seen enough shark movies and enough storm
>   movies. A month later they came back to me and said they really wanted
>   me to write a movie called “Sharknato” (at least that’s what I thought
>   they said), and I asked what sharks had to do with the North Atlantic
>   Treaty Organization? I was suddenly seeing the army battling sharks
>   invading Europe… But they said “No, Sharknado!” They gave me about
>   half a page of notes which I read and replied “This is the most
>   ridiculous thing I’ve ever read… I’M IN!”

So those quotes if you consider them canon seem to answer the question.